# Spring MVC Test Framework: Why doesn't test dispatcher servlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**I've got:** trivial Spring MVC sample app. I configure `DispatcherServlet` to handle all requests which start with `dispatcher/`.

**Problem:** After deploying to Tomcat, if I try to go to `localhost:8080` page I get `The requested resource (/) is not available.`. But I can go through `localhost:8080/dispatcher` path.

**Questions:**

1. Why does `simple` test works if we do `mockMvc.perform(get("/"))` instead of `mockMvc.perform(get("/dispatcher"))`?

**Code:**

*web.xml:*

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dispatcher/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

*Controller:*

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

*Test:*

```
@Test
public void simple() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(model().attribute("message", "Hello world!"))
            .andExpect(view().name("hello"));
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: @Rohit I just wondering why Spring MVC test framework doesn't take into acount dispatcher servlet. I mean dispatcher servlet maps only `dispatcher/*` paths, but simple test feel allright with `/` path

Comment: @Rohit no exceptions. Actually the question is why my test works if they shouldn;t

Answer (score 2):

> Problem: After deploying to Tomcat, if I try to go to localhost:8080
>   page I get The requested resource (/) is not available.. But I can go
>   through localhost:8080/dispatcher path.

Accessing your controller from the Servlet Container's perspective - what you're doing when you type localhost:8080/dispatcher - requires a lot of information in the url path. For example, your `HelloController` is

1. configured to be handle by the `mvc-dispatcher` Servlet
2. `mvc-dispatcher` Servlet is declared in a web application (defined by your web.xml)
3. there could be multiple Servlets in your web application
4. the web application is deployed to your Servlet container (Tomcat)
5. there could be multiple web applications in the Servlet Container

There's lots of ambiguity in resolving a url when you take all this into consideration. As @san krish pointed out, and assuming you've deployed your application to Tomcat's root context, you can force everything through `mvc-dispatcher` and map it to /* as default, and end up serving your `HelloController` from `localhost:8080/`.

> Why does simple test works if we do mockMvc.perform(get("/")) instead
>   of mockMvc.perform(get("/dispatcher"))?

Accessing your controller from mockMvc in your test is pretty localized. Depending on how your test was set up, a MockMvc instance was created either from:

1. **MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)** - here your controller is passed directly to the test for testing, therefore MockMvc knows nothing about a `mvc-dispatcher` and it's "/dispatcher" path.
2. **MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)** - here, the test class is annotated with a `@ContextConfiguration` that points to your "mvc-dispatcher" xml or @Configuration class. In this situation, MockMvc would be acting on everything localized under "mvc-dispatcher" so there's no need to reference the "dispatcher" in the path.

Answer (score 1):

In the `web.xml` map the wildcard entry

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It will pass all in-coming requests to the dispatcher servlet